# Can I keep get out of Unity editor features if I'm using ECS Pattern?

Tags: unity

I'm learning about `ECS Pattern` to use it in my Unity game, as I saw until now, most of stuffs is created by code.

As I know, each Unity `GameObject` is a `Entity` which contains many of `Components` and GameObjects are instantiated by code (created by my script, for example).

My question is, when I use `ECS Pattern`, can I keep using the bunch of features offered by Unity editor (like Prefabs, ScriptObjects, Drag Dropg to position, etc) or I need to control all of them by code?

Comment: I suppose in theory you could create everything programmatically, but it might be useful to use prefabs as blueprints and use script objects to easily attach behaviors to entities.

Comment: What you mean is that I can attach `Component` to Prefabs and instantiating prefab instead of a "empty" `GameObject`?

Comment: That's exactly what you do. If nothing else, it auto-generates a lot of code for you behind the scenes.